Add new tags in autogenerated Spring Data Prometheus metric spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds
Is it possible to add new tags into autogenerated Spring Data Prometheus metric spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds?
I have the following JpaRepository:
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, String> {
}

Currentely spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds published at actuator/prometheus has only 4 tags:
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="save",repository="TaskRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 36813.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="save",repository="TaskRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 22.900531457

How to add some custom tags there?
